# Are all 110 million parameter in bert are trainable

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, nlp, bert, transformer

I am trying to understand are all these 110 million parameters trainable of bert uncased model. Is there any non trainable parameters in this image below?

By trainable I understand they are initialized with random weight and during pretraining these weights are backpropagated and updated.

[image: Bert 110 Million Parameters]

Comment: what is the source of your table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All these parameters are trainable.

Note that in normal Transformers it is typical to have fixed (non-trainable) positional embeddings, but [in BERT they are learned](https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/58#issuecomment-572287540).

Note also the "pooler" component, which is an extra projection that was not mentioned in the paper, but which [the authors commented on later](https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/43#issuecomment-435980269).